# How can I export all dataframes into an Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a notebook open with about 45 dataframes. I would like to export all of them into a single Excel file with each dataframe being it's own tab in Excel.

Is there an easy way to do this without having to write each tab out manually?

Thank you!

Comment: First make a list of all dataframes sitting in the memory, then iterate over it and save each one as an Excel tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the link [Example: Pandas Excel with multiple dataframes](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html)

You can then as suggested by @delimiter create a list of the names

```
import pandas as pd
# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [21, 22, 23, 24]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [31, 32, 33, 34]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

list = [df1,df2,df3]
names = ['df1','df2','df3']
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=names[i])
```

Comment: please check now. I think there was a mistake in the name. 
I used f'{item}' to pass a string of the dataframe name

Comment: Thanks for this. It ran, but now I'm getting an invalid sheet name error. Interestingly, it's trying to name the Excel tabs after the column headers in the dataframe themselves, not the dataframe names I've put in the list.

Comment: Here is the list in case I'm missing something:

list= [df, allthatapply, check1, check2, check3, check4, check5, ids, likert1, open1, open1_count, open2, open2_count, open3, open3_count, open4, open4_count, open5, open5_count, open6, open6_count, other1, other1_count, other2, other2_count, other3, other3_count, other4, other4_count, other5, other5_count, other6, other6_count, rank1, response]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

first create a list of all the dataframes that you need to write.

```
l=[df1,df2,df3...]

writer=pd.ExcelWriter('multi_df.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')

for i,df in enumerate(l):
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="df_"+str(i+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a pandas excel writer instance and name the excel file

```
    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter('Customer_Details.xlsx')
```

If you don't include a file path like 'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\File_Name.xlsx', it will save to your default folder, that is where the file you're reading from is located.

#2. Write each dataframe to a worksheet with a name

```
    dfName.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name = 'Name', index = False)
    dfAddress.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name = 'Address', index = False)
    dfContact.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name = 'Contact', index = False)
```

#3. Close the instance

```
xlwriter.close()
```

source [youtu.be](https://youtu.be/zwFYdf7GUdc)